# python - while loop structure

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help to construct a working while loop.
my code goes like this

```
class Bot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.woke = False
        while self.woke == False:
            self.wake_word() # --> when it predicts wake word self.woke changes to True
            while self.woke == True:
                self.voice_recognition() # --> takes audio turns it to a spoke.txt file
                break
            self.chat() # --> reads the spoke.txt and finds a response
            self.respond() # --> speaks the responds using pyttsx3
```

the code works perfectly but only for one time..it does what I want it to do but for once and then the script stops.
I need to run it until I give the command to stop it using

```
sys.exit(0) # in a function
```

meaning when it responses it starts listening again (self.voice_recognition() function) and again does the chat() and finds a respond().

Comment: Did you mean to use a local variable `woke` on the first and second lines of `__init__()`? Or maybe just `while True:`?

Comment: Do you need to set `self.woke = False` before `break` so the outer loop will keep iterating or does `self.voice_recognition()` take care of that?

Comment: @quamrana self.woke was first defined in the     __init__()

Comment: @JNevill  self.voice_recognition() doesn't change the value of self.woke and I need the bot to keep listening for new orders

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are looking for, but try this -

```
class Bot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.woke = False
        while self.woke == False:
            self.wake_word() # --> when it predicts wake word self.woke changes to True
            while self.woke == True:
                self.voice_recognition() # --> takes audio turns it to a spoke.txt file
                self.woke=False
                break
                

            self.chat() # --> reads the spoke.txt and finds a response
            self.respond() # --> speaks the responds using pyttsx3
```

Comment: this is very close to what I want wake_word started again but when the wake word was detected the bot responded with the old respond from the first time and didn't listen it's like voice_recognition() didn't start
            # example:
            # prediction started
            # python # --> wake word
            # listening...
            # hi
            # bot: hello there

            #statrs predicting again
            # python #--> wake word
            # bot: hello there

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the way I'm capturing audio.. (I had to close the stream).
what happened was that each time the voice_recognition() was called the stream was already open so the data didn't change and that causes an infinite loop inside the function which caused it to not work how it was supposed to

the final code the was correctly working is this

```
self.wake_word()
    while True:
        self.voice_recognition()
        self.chat()
        self.respond()
```

really simple and straight forward, the problem was with it the function not the while loop structure.
Thanks for anyone who took the time and tried to answer I'm sure your answers / comments were correct as this wasn't about the while loop structure yet a simple unrecognized missing code.